# Why can't I find peace over the use of articles?

Tags: articles

The two questions I am about to pose might be stupid (should there be a comma here, by the way?) but I checked and rechecked the rules and still can´t wrap my mind around it. Maybe there are several ways to do this!

This is what I am wondering about (The first sentence is for the sake of context):

> For instance, when a large field of rapeseed withers, bees can’t find food in this area anymore. As a result, a lot of beekeepers have to feed their bees from June until **the** next year’s spring.
>
> What are the consequences of **the/a** decrease of bees?

In the first sentence I wrote, "the next year's spring" but then I had second thoughts about. Sure, it's this very spring, but it is always next year's spring when June is the starting point in the year before. Should it be omitted?

In the second sentence, I started out with, "a" since I had heard something like that many times before. But shouldn't it be, "the" since it is a specific kind of decrease?!

Maybe I am thinking too much?

Comment: I'm not clear about what you are asking.  Is the question specifically whether you should use "**the** next year's spring" or "**a** next year's spring" or just "next year's spring" with no article?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First question: *next year/month/week/Spring/Tuesday* conventionally means "the next one from now". So if you mean the next one from some specified point in the past or future, you need *the next*.

So *the next year's Spring*. I think *the next Spring* is more natural, but *the next year's Spring* is possible, and more precise.

Second question: *the decrease* and *a decrease* are both possible, even in this context. *The decrease* means "the decrease alluded to or implied by the previous text", while *a decrease* means "any decrease", but I can't find any operative difference in meaning in this context.